# Python oauth2 - no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-2.7

Python beginner

```
>>> import oauth2
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2/**init**.py", line 32, in 
>       import httplib2
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 801, in 
>       class HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

I don't understand the error
Why do I get that ?

- Ubuntu 10.04
- python 2.7 (built from source)

Comment: It is mentioned on httplib official docs that `HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was compiled with SSL support`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned on [httplib official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) that `HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was compiled with SSL support`.